# UIScrollView only scrolling to left by clicking UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

In my app I have a scrollView. It should only scroll to the right when a UIButton is clicked. Scrolling to the left should always be possible. I found a solution like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
    {
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.x < oldX) {
            [aScrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(oldX, aScrollView.contentOffset.y)];
        } else {
            oldX = aScrollView.contentOffset.x;
        }

    }
```

This code stops it from scrolling to the left, but i can't make this work for the right side. Any ideas how this could be done?

Thanks

Comment: Couldnt you change the if statement to be `>` instead of `<`?

Comment: What is happening when you do that?

Comment: it scrolls to the left when touching the display. and I`m not able to set the method for the button so that when the button is klicked it scrolls to the right. I think I should set the contentOffset new in this method. but not sure about it.

Comment: Just have a boolean variable and put inside the if statement ` && !boolVar`, and whenever you press your button, toggle boolVar.